# Binding Source Control

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

I have a binding source control in my form. I utilize the binding source current_changed event in the form for doing some special tasks, the problem that I faces is, in the form_Load event I make a list as the datasource of this binding source and the current_changed event has been called multiple times. Why it's like that?

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Employee> listEmployee = new List<Employee>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.EmployeeName = "user" + i;
            emp.EmployeeAddress = "Address" + i;
            listEmployee.Add(emp);
        }
        bindingSource1.DataSource = listEmployee;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
    }

    private void bindingSource1_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hai");
    }
}
public class Employee
{
    private string Name;
    private string Address;

    public string EmployeeName {
        get {return Name;}
        set { Name = value; }
    }

    public string EmployeeAddress
    {
        get { return Address; }
        set { Address = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you adding items one at a time?

Comment: No I Create a list and make this list as the data source of the bindingsource control.But the  current_changed event called many times (only in the form load). Once the form is loaded it works normally

Comment: The documentation does say that CurrentChanged is raised _"[when] the membership of the underlying List changes, which causes Position to refer to a different item"_ which changing the datasource must trigger. You can either set a `loading` flag in `Form_Load` and use that to ignore the event, or - probably better - wire the event up after the data has been loaded.

Comment: how about showing the code to make the situation reproducible?

Comment: @Mong Zhu       I have updated my question with simple code

Comment: @ stuartd        I load the data into a list initially and then makes the list  as the datasource of the binding source and assigns binding source as the datasource for the gridveiw in this case. So Why this current changed event has been called thrice here. It should be only once I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my special case I created a flag on the page load and prevented the execution of currentchanged event more than once. I couldn't find any other way to solve it.